# "like" button in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, spservices

I have a subsite in SharePoint 2010 forum type and I need to add a button "like" next to the "comment" button.

[image]

I searched the internet for a way to do this with spservices, though I just found in asp.net

Would anyone tell me if this is possible or only with programming?

Comment: You need to add Ratings on the library and instead of Stars have them shows as 'Likes'. If it was SP2013 I would walk you through but not familiar with it in 2010 and no environment to test

Comment: Are you wanting this to actually integrate with Facebook or store the likes in a list on your SP environment?

Comment: Nothing integrated with facebook. The user will post on the blog and will have the "like" button for each post made